Convert image of table into numeric
I often face the task of extracting tabular data that comes in difficult-to-parse form, most frequently as image or non-parsable PDF. I would like to write (in Java or Python) an OCR tool that reads as input a screenshot from the clipboard (e.g. after using the snipping tool and CTRL+C), and returns a panda DataFrame or tabular data in other form back into the clipboard, so that one only has to press CTRL+V to paste it into Excel. It should be a quick in-and-out type tool and not a PDF-to-spreadsheet or Excel-image-data-import function, as all of them are typically too slow and tend to be surprisingly error-prone.
I'm ready to use pre-trained OCR-type models for detecting numbers if there are any that can be run locally in e.g. a python environment. All the image-data is overwhelmingly numeric and in machine-letter form - i.e. not handwritten or otherwise complicated. I put an example of a screenshot below. The tables aren't super large. My feeling is that an OCR model should have no difficulty identifying the numbers there.
My only unfortunate constraint is that I cannot use pytesseract. I am bound by what I can install on my work-machine, which does not allow the required binaries. Would anyone have any other suggestions of how best to convert an image like below into numeric data? Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

